# How to eliminate "duplicate" URL MySQL rows which may or may not start with www?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, drupal, duplicates

I've been using a Drupal module called [FeedAPI De-Dupe](http://drupal.org/project/feedapi_dedupe) to remove duplicate records from my site's (MySQL) database. The module does a great job, but I'm still left with some "duplicates" when the URLs sometimes contain "www" and sometimes don't. The [code handling the duplicate detection](http://drupalcode.org/viewvc/drupal/contributions/modules/feedapi_dedupe/feedapi_dedupe.module?revision=1.1.2.1&content-type=text%2Fplain&view=co&pathrev=DRUPAL-6--1) is:

```
case 0: //url-based
    $sql = "SELECT n.nid
  FROM {node} n
  INNER JOIN {feedapi_node_item} i ON i.nid=n.nid
  WHERE type='%s' AND url = '%s'
  LIMIT 1";

  $dnid = db_result(db_query($sql, 
          variable_get('feedapi_dedupe_content_type', feedapi_dedupe_content_type()),
          $url));
break;
```

Is there a way to modify the SQL to also handle the www/no-www case? If not, is there a way to handle it in a separate SQL query instead?

Comment: What does `$url` contains? The full URL, or just the domain?

Comment: kiamlanu, $url contains the full URL, such as:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374539/how-to-eliminate-duplicate-url-mysql-rows-which-may-or-may-not-start-with-www

Comment: Doh! The code I posted is only half the battle. It avoids duplicates when adding new entries. Another function removes duplicates already added:

  case 0: //url-based
      $sql = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(i.nid SEPARATOR ',') as nids, `title`, `url`, count(*) as num 
    FROM {node} n
    INNER JOIN {feedapi_node_item} i ON i.nid=n.nid
    WHERE type='%s' 
    GROUP BY `url`
    HAVING `url` IS NOT NULL AND url!='' AND num>1
    ORDER BY num desc
    LIMIT %d";
  break;

I hate to even ask, since you've both been super helpful, but any thoughts on this section would also be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Wow, code doesn't come through cleanly in these comments. Let me try that again...

Doh! I just realized that the code I posted is only half the battle. It avoids duplicates when adding the new entries.

The feedapi_dedupe_clean_duplicates function removes duplicates already added (see the bottom of the file): http://bit.ly/beRwVQ

I hate to even ask, since you've both been super helpful, but any thoughts on adding www/no-www checking to that function would also be greatly appreciated! Even a pointer in the right direction would be helpful. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe:

```
case 0: //url-based
  $sql = "SELECT n.nid
  FROM {node} n
  INNER JOIN {feedapi_node_item} i ON i.nid=n.nid
  WHERE type='%s' AND (url = '%s' OR url = '%s')
  LIMIT 1";

  $dnid = db_result(
    db_query(
      $sql, 
      variable_get('feedapi_dedupe_content_type', feedapi_dedupe_content_type()),
      $url,
      preg_replace('@//www.@', '//' $url)));
break;
```

However, I cannot test it myself right now.

Comment: I don't think that will work because the url field contains the full url (ie, "http://example.com" not "example.com").

Comment: Ok, I modified the code according to that. Still untested, and probably need some modifications, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that `$url` contains the full URL (including the `http://` part), the following code should do what you are asking for:

```
preg_match('@^(?:http://)?([^/]+)@i', $url, $matches);
$sql = "SELECT n.nid
  FROM {node} n
  INNER JOIN {feedapi_node_item} i ON i.nid=n.nid
  WHERE type='%s' AND (url = '%s' OR url = '%s')";

$dnid = db_result(db_query_range($sql, 
  variable_get('feedapi_dedupe_content_type', feedapi_dedupe_content_type()),
   'http://www.' . $matches[1], 'http://' . $matches[1], 0, 1)
);
```

If then the URL contained in the database contains values like `http://example.com/directory, then you can use the following code:

```
preg_match('@^(?:http://)?([^/]+)@i', $url, $matches);
$sql = "SELECT n.nid
  FROM {node} n
  INNER JOIN {feedapi_node_item} i ON i.nid=n.nid
  WHERE type='%s' AND (url LIKE '%s' OR url LIKE '%s')";

$dnid = db_result(db_query_range($sql, 
  variable_get('feedapi_dedupe_content_type', feedapi_dedupe_content_type()),
   'http://www.' . $matches[1] . '/%', 'http://' . $matches[1] . '/%', 0, 1)
);
```

In Drupal, if you want to limit the number of rows obtained from a query, you need to use `db_query_range()`.